# C# Blazor / MAUI - Is there any way to set two conditionals to a variable to determine its state?

Tags: c#, blazor, maui

I'm wondering if it's at all possible to have two separate conditions to 'hide' and 'show' a div in Blazor / MAUI

```
    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            Valid = false;
            
            HideMenu = false;
        }

        public bool Valid { get; set; }

        public bool HideMenu { get; set; }

    }
```

```
<div id="contentBar" class="@NavMenuCssClass">

@code
{

   private string NavMenuCssClass => 
(collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null) || (currentUser.HideMenu ? "collapse" : null);

}
```

This is how I assume it would be done, but the code is obviously incorrect.

The idea behind the code here is having two different factors at play to hide this menu of mine, one is to hide it on button presses when navigating across pages, the other is the have it hide when a successful login occurs on a separate page.

I've tried to make methods static and call the entire NavMenu in different pages to hide it, but that seems to not function as likely I need to affect the current instance of NavMenu, and not the entire class itself.

Any suggestions or a flat out "no, this is not possible" would be great. Thanks

Comment: `... => collapseNavMenu || currentUser.HideMenu ? "collapse" : null`? Has nothing to do with Blazor specifically.

Comment: So glad this is the assistance obtained from Stack Overflow in 2024. Now I see why everyone is moving to AI platforms to assist in programming.

Comment: If you are genuinely happy about received assistance, why does it make you understand why everyone is moving to AI? And if you are being sarcastic about the inadequate level of assistance received, what is the basis of that, given that you were given the actual code that answers your question 9 minutes after you posted it?